# How to pass parameters to Angular service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, service

I have a service  in my Angular application that requires two dependencies in its constructor: UntypedFormGroup and DestroyRef. Currently, I am injecting these dependencies directly into the service's constructor in my module.

Now, I want to find a way to provide these dependencies to the service from a component without injecting them into the component's constructor.

Here's my simplified service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CalculateFieldsService {
  constructor(
    private jsonForm: UntypedFormGroup,
    private destroy: DestroyRef
  ) {
    // Service constructor
  }

  // Rest of the service code...
}
```

How I can pass those two parameters. From providers or how I can?

I appreciate any guidance or examples on how to achieve this effectively. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I want to help :) but before I have a question, why does this class need to be an `Injectable`? I don't see any DI provider in the constructor of it. Can it simply be a class that you construct and use inside your component?

Comment: That's true! But imagine that we have DI providers in the constructor :)

Comment: alright. If that's the case. Can these properties not be part of the constructor? have them as properties and initialize them afterwards with an `init` function, or something similar